# Can't switch to install mode

Tags: windows, server, permissions, remote-access

So, I'm trying to install web module to software which the company I work for made and have the following issue. When I try to run the service which uses curl to connect and transfer data to and from MySQL, It's not starting and I get the error 1067.
The reasons where narrowed to permission and mainly the inability to switch to install mode. The operating system is server 2016 and the machine is used as terminal server.
I'm connected with remote session which may be the reason. But it turns out the people working there also use remote only and don't have access to the physical machine.
So none of us can switch to install mode and I can't find anything useful on the web.
Is it even possible to switch ?

Tried basically everything on the web.